# Is there a 30-pin LVDS cable extension for Macbook Pro display panel?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware

I'm trying to convert my old 13" unibody MacBook Pro (mid-2012) display into an external monitor. I purchased a controller board from eBay that supports the display panel of MacBook Pro. I am wondering how to connect LVDS cable from MBP to the controller board. Controller board already has it's own LVDS cable. I'm wondering if there is any kind of extension available that can be used to connect these two cables. I'm not sure what would be the right terminology but I guess 30-pin LVDS female to 30-pin LVDS female port? Not sure. Below are the images of both.

Please note that there is no way for me to connect Controller board's LVDS cable directly to display panel of MacBook Pro since this laptop has display glass infused to the display panel. I would really like to not go through the procedure of temporarily removing display glass using hair dryer heat. Also I don't want to take display panel off the Apple casing that it comes in originally.

Thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I think it will be hard to make it work without disassembling the whole screen. The main reason for this is that the pinout of the connector coming out from the screen you attached in pic (whether 30 or 40 pins) is customised by Apple and may not correspond to the 30 (or 40) pins pinout of the connector soldered on the screen. For example, on some model I have seen that the producer puts display, camera and mic all together.
Even thought you will be able to find an hypothetical female-female adapter, then, it is not 100% sure that will be pin correspondence.

One think you could do, if you want to proceed in finding an 1-1 adapter, is finding the schematics of the Apple LVSD cable that comes out of the screen and check for pin compatibility.If positive, then look for a female-female adapter.

Or, in case you have money to spend into a new adapter (or build one yourself) have a look here<: http://dp2mbpr.rozsnyo.com/ or here https://hackaday.com/2013/07/05/macbook-pro-retina-display-with-a-normal-computer/

Ciao!